# align text of span in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` tag in my site.

I want to align the text of the span on the center of the page.

```
<span id="notice">Please Read the notice</span>
```

I am doing it like below using the CSS.

```
#notice{
     color:#D05679;
     font-family: Signika; 
     font-size:15px;
     text-align:center;

   }
```

But this is not working. Please suggest.

PS: Thanks everyone for the answers. They all work. I was doing a silly mistake.

Comment: Center how, vertically? Horizontally? Both?

Comment: Horizontally center aligned

Answer (score 5):

try this..

```css
#notice{
     color:#D05679;
     font-family: Signika; 
     font-size:15px;
     text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="notice">
    <span >Please Read the notice</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

add display: block to your CSS.

```
#notice{
 color:#D05679;
 font-family: Signika; 
 font-size:15px;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
}
```

To explain: `text-align: center` will center the content of the span within the boundaries of the span. But a span element, by default, is only as wide as its content:

```
|content|
```

Whereas some other elements such as `div` and `p`, by default, occupy the full width available to them:

```
|content                                                                                  |
```

The difference is that a `span` is set to `display:inline` while `div` and `p` are set to `display:block`.

Answer (score 3):

`text-align` affects text inside the element BUT a `span` is an inline element by default and so is only as wide as it's contents. so while the text inside the span *is* centered you can't tell because span only as wide as the text.

So the solution here is just add `text-align:center` to the parent element...not the span.

```css
body {
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<span id="notice">Please Read the notice</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

SPAN is not block element, so, by default, it can't be used for alignin text.
You can, ac above:
- set display:block, it will take 100% width and then will work text-align:center
- set display:inline-block; and margin: 0 auto; in this case SPAN will be same with as content, but will be aligned by center of page. 
It depends on your layout.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
<div id="notice">
<span >Please Read the notice</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use in style may work for you

```
#notice{
    color:#D05679;
    font-family: Signika; 
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euh7pwjd/)  and **CSS**

```
#notice{
     color:#D05679;
     font-family: Signika; 
     font-size:15px;
     text-align:center;
     display: block;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this one:

```css
span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <span>Please Read the notice</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox properties.

HTML

```
<div id="notice">
<div>Please Read the notice</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#notice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%
}

#notice > div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

For more details you can see this link : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/